# PHP Mysqli prepared statments TEXT, TINYTEXT, HUGETEXT, etc data character

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I need to use [TEXT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.htmlZ) datatypes in my website in order to store custom (yes, html code is blocked, bbcode is used instead) pages made by users. When using mysqli prepared statments you need to specify a [data character](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) ([here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) is a link to the documentation). It does not list a data character for `TEXT`, my guess is that I should use `b` because it is for blob, but I would like to confirm. Secondly, is there any difference between `TINYTEXT`, `TEXT`, `HUGETEXT` and etc in the character I should use?

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6397459/php-mysqli-bind-param-type-for-text.

Answer (score 0):

Rule of thumb: you can use `s` for any field type.

Comment: Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6397459/php-mysqli-bind-param-type-for-text), it explains why that is not always good...