# Pass everything as string in PHP mysql_stmt::bind_param()

Tags: php, mysqli, parameters, prepared-statement, bindparam

From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php),

> types
>
> A string that contains one or more characters which specify the types
> for the corresponding bind variables
>
> Type specification chars
> Character Description
> i corresponding variable has type integer
> d corresponding variable has type double
> s corresponding variable has type string
> b corresponding variable is a blob and will be sent in packets

How wrong is it to send everything as "s"? I am trying to make a dynamic function and for that I need to detect the data types and build the `types` string from that. But if everything can be passed as string without any problem, then I can skip the hassle.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6397459/php-mysqli-bind-param-type-for-text.

Comment: @chris85 Ah, thanks. Shall I delete this question then?

Comment: @lonekingc4 You can or it can be just marked as duplicate.

Comment: @TareqMahmood Thanks brother. Yeah, marked.

Comment: I wouldn't say this is a bad question, it was clear what you were asking; so I'd leave this. I think this falls under the meta discussion on the topic: `Duplicate questions are not necessarily bad; different descriptions of the same problem help future visitors to find the answers they're looking for.`